# How can i make better performance for my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

i have been reading some articles about "in statement" for sql. i learned "IN" creates some bad performance. i would like to make better performance above my codes. Can you give me some advises to achieve this, please?

```
select 
    v.Id,  
    v.MissingVehicleFlag,  
    v.Make,  
    v.OatsModelId,  
    v.Model,  
    v.PersonalisedName,  
    v.RegistrationPlate, 
    v.ImageUrl,  
    v.ImageCropStartingX,  
    v.ImageCropStartingY, 
    v.LastModified, 
    v.Account_Id, 
    v.Deleted
from RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.Vehicles v  
    where v.Id in(
        select v1.Id
        from RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.Vehicles v1 
        except
        select v2.Id from RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.VehiclesV2 v2
        )
```

Comment: What you have now is a good way to go.  However, if Vehicles and Vehicles2 are large tables, a where clause might be in order.  You can also do a left join to Vehicles2, but I wouldn't expect any improvement.

Comment: `in` is slow, also using a join should perform better

Comment: Pls show us the execution plan, we can all only guess this way. DDL for the table would be nice also.

Comment: Yakshemash ! How many rows do you have in both tables ? Are there any indexes ? Chenqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select 
    v.Id,  
    v.MissingVehicleFlag,  
    v.Make,  
    v.OatsModelId,  
    v.Model,  
    v.PersonalisedName,  
    v.RegistrationPlate, 
    v.ImageUrl,  
    v.ImageCropStartingX,  
    v.ImageCropStartingY, 
    v.LastModified, 
    v.Account_Id, 
    v.Deleted
from RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.Vehicles v  
    where NOT EXISTS (
        select v2.Id 
        from RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.VehiclesV2 v2
        WHERE v.Id = v2.Id
        )
```

And make sure there is an index on `Id` in both `RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.Vehicles` and `RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.VehiclesV2`

Comment: I would think the first 'exists' isn't needed since every record should match (they are the same table)

Comment: I couuldn't help but wander, why would it perform better than the properly indexed original query?

Comment: @dean `EXISTS` can perform faster that `IN` in some cases

Comment: @DStanley Yes, and IN can perform better than EXISTS in some cases also :) Only two reasons to avoid IN have nothing to do with performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    v.Id,  
    v.MissingVehicleFlag,  
    v.Make,  
    v.OatsModelId,  
    v.Model,  
    v.PersonalisedName,  
    v.RegistrationPlate, 
    v.ImageUrl,  
    v.ImageCropStartingX,  
    v.ImageCropStartingY, 
    v.LastModified, 
    v.Account_Id, 
    v.Deleted
FROM RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.Vehicles v  
LEFT JOIN RobbinsuatLatest.dbo.VehiclesV2 v2 on v.Id = v2.Id
WHERE v2.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Are you saying that anti semi joins are to be preferred over EXISTS and IN? Aside the nullable columns problem and IN clause, could you pls explain why?

Comment: Dean... you are probably right here. It appears that 'not exists' usually results in better performance to a left join w/ check for null. http://bicortex.com/which-one-should-i-use-not-exists-not-in-outer-apply-except-and-left-outer-join-performance-optimization/